# Opening a telnet connection as pseudotty

Tags: sockets, linux-device-driver, telnet, tty

I am trying to create a number of connections to a cyclades server. This is done by using telnet to an IP address (IP_ADDR) and a port number (PORT). It works fine when I create one active connection but I need to run a script to map these connections to /dev/PSEUDO_TTY_PORT, which another program needs to access. I am running CentOS so the cyclades-server-client modules are not available and rtelnet isn't available either.

I believe the command should look something like this:

`telnet IP_ADDR PORT /dev/PSEUDO_TTY_PORT`

But that doesn't work, does anyone know how to properly map it?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to use something else in between, for example, `socat`.

Comment: @0andriy Would this open up the pty as well?

Comment: Yes. Just read a documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @0andriy, managed to do so using

```
socat PTY, link=/dev/PSEUDO_TTY_PORT,raw,echo=0 TCP4:IP_ADDR:PORT
```